# How to add, subtract two or more DTPicker value in VB6

Tags: vb6

[here is my GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Heg.png)

```
    Dim d1, d2, d3 As Date
    Dim d4 As Integer
    Dim x As Long

    Option Explicit

    Private Sub Command1_Click()
    d1 = TimePicker.Value + DTPicker1.Value 
    d2 = TimePicker2.Value + DTPicker3.Value

    x = DateDiff("h", d1, d2) 

    MsgBox x

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Load()

    TimePicker.Format = dtpTime
    TimePicker2.Format = dtpTime

    End Sub

============================================
```

i want to calculate more number of hours in three or more days, I can only add two days it gaves me a value of 16hours and its correct, if i add more day it will add 24hours so it become 40 how can i fix this.I want to get 8hrs per day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `x = DateDiff("h", d1, d2)`, you will get the number of **hours** between d1 and d2.
If you use `x = DateDiff("d", d1, d2)`, you will get the number of **days** between d1 and d2.

If you want to get 8 hours for each day, just multiply the DateDiff value by 8:

```
x = DateDiff("d", d1, d2) * 8
```

Comment: I want to count the time in  and time out for a day , for example I time in 7am and time out at 3 pm.